# Run js code in blazor without having to call a function

Tags: blazor

I couldn't find anything that would allow me to run js code in blazor without having to call a function from a js file and I'm wondering if it is possible, since it would be much easier to just write some js in my blazor component.

Something like this:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(
        { 
            // Write JS in here, like this:
            console.log("i possible hope this is");
        });

        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Is something like the example above a possibility?

Comment: May be not possible .. that's why Blazor framework has IJSRuntime

Answer (score 1):

you have to call a function but can work around as eval is a function takes JS code
used it to inject JS from library projects
https://blog.ppedv.de/post/Razor-Classlibrary-JavaScript-einbinden